# Android. RecyclerView track viewed items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have two RecyclerView inside the NestedScrollView and I need track viewed items of my RecyclerViews. But problem that using nestedScrollView the recycler pattern doesn’t work and all the views will be loaded at once because wrap_content needs the height of complete RecyclerView so it will draw all child Views at once.
Is there any way to  track of the viewed items with this approach? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

never use `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView` because your `ViewHolders` will not be recycled and you will be in danger of `OutOfMemoeryExceptions`, it may work for lists with small sizes but as the list size increases it becomes worse,
instead of using one `ScrollView` and 2 `RecyclerView` as child

**you have to completely remove `ScrollView` and instead of that, use one `RecyclerView`  with multitype `ViewHolders`, in other words you need to combine those 2 `RecyclerView` in on `RecyclerView` .**

To achieving this you can combine those adapters manually or you can use `ConcatAdapter` that depends on what you want, this [link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/merge-adapters-sequentially-with-mergeadapter-294d2942127a) may also help you if you want to use `ConcatAdapter` but that is not necessary.

then you can have different approaches to track the visibility of viewHolders like `layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()` and etc.